# How to start Titanium iPad app in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, ipad, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using `Ti.UI.orientation = Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT` on app startup, which turns it to landscape, however there's a short rotation animation.

Is there a way to have it launch already in landscape to avoid this?

Comment: Forcing orientation modes is considered a bad practice, see: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Orientation-section-src-29004932_Orientation-Limitingorientationmodessupportedbyawindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `tiapp.xml`:

```
<iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
        </orientations>
</iphone>
```

Note that you'll still need to provide orientation preferences for the window, but I believe this will solve your issue on launch.  You'll need to flush your `/build/iphone/` (or similar) folder for the changes to apply.

Comment: I already had my tiapp.xml set up like that, still getting the rotation on app startup unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The code you give in your example, `Ti.UI.orientation = Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT` is deprecated per http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI-module.

Instead you set a window's `orientationModes` property after the window has been created. Here is what I have in an app I wrote where I'm restricting devices to portrait mode:

```
        var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: st.ui.theme.backgroundColor,
        fullscreen: true,
        navBarHidden: true,
        exitOnClose: true
    });
    win.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];
```

Instead of `win.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];` you should try `win.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT];` and see where it gets you.